# Not able to get property values of an object in Hubspot using the API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, postman, hubspot

I am trying to get the property values of the Deal Object in Hubspot. I am able to see them via Postman. However, when I try to make the same call via Node.js it doesn't give me the property values.

This is the API URL: [https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=demo&includeAssociations=true&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=hubspot_owner_id&properties=amount&limit=10](https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=demo&includeAssociations=true&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=hubspot_owner_id&properties=amount)

With Postman, I am able to get the dealname, dealstage and the rest of the properties that are specified in the URL

> {
>       "deals": [
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22900219,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "MadKudu",
>                       "timestamp": 1525078747520,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "MadKudu",
>                               "timestamp": 1525078747520,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461237738053,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461237738053,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22901709,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461241957842,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461241957842,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461241957842,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461241957842,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22902634,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461244142358,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461244142358,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461244142358,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461244142358,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22905614,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461248390906,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461248390906,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461248390906,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461248390906,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22905684,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461248467787,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461248467787,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461248467787,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461248467787,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22906614,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "kola11-national",
>                       "timestamp": 1461249908869,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "kola11-national",
>                               "timestamp": 1461249908869,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461249908869,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461249908869,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22907409,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "alok111-national",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250718805,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "alok111-national",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250718805,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250718805,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250718805,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22907704,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "kola54321-national",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250972802,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "kola54321-national",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250972802,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250972802,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250972802,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22907709,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250988473,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250988473,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461250988473,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461250988473,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           },
>           {
>               "portalId": 62515,
>               "dealId": 22908009,
>               "isDeleted": false,
>               "associations": {
>                   "associatedVids": [],
>                   "associatedCompanyIds": [],
>                   "associatedDealIds": []
>               },
>               "properties": {
>                   "dealname": {
>                       "value": "$username",
>                       "timestamp": 1461251673754,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealname",
>                               "value": "$username",
>                               "timestamp": 1461251673754,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "num_associated_contacts": {
>                       "value": "0",
>                       "timestamp": 0,
>                       "source": "CALCULATED",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "num_associated_contacts",
>                               "value": "0",
>                               "source": "CALCULATED",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "dealstage": {
>                       "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                       "timestamp": 1461251673754,
>                       "source": "API",
>                       "sourceId": null,
>                       "versions": [
>                           {
>                               "name": "dealstage",
>                               "value": "appointmentscheduled",
>                               "timestamp": 1461251673754,
>                               "source": "API",
>                               "sourceVid": []
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   }
>               },
>               "imports": [],
>               "stateChanges": []
>           }
>       ],
>       "hasMore": true,
>       "offset": 22908009 }

Whereas with Node.js, I am not able to get the property values Here is the output from Node.js

> { deals:    [ { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22900219,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22901709,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22902634,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22905614,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22905684,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22906614,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22907409,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22907704,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22907709,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] },
>        { portalId: 62515,
>          dealId: 22908009,
>          isDeleted: false,
>          associations: [Object],
>          properties: [Object],
>          imports: [],
>          stateChanges: [] } ],   hasMore: true,   offset: 22908009 }

As you might observe with the property key, it shows [object] as it's value, when it should actually specify the values of the properties.

Here is the Node.js code that I had written-

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
const url='https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey=demo&includeAssociations=true&properties=dealname&properties=dealstage&properties=closedate&properties=hubspot_owner_id&properties=amount&limit=10';

fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json()) // Transform the data into json
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

  })
```

Here is a reference to the Deals API Documentation in Hubspot: https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/deals/get-all-deals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is all there. It's showing `[Object]` because you're doing a `console.log`, which doesn't output EVERYTHING. Try this instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

That will show you EVERYTHING (and the `2` makes it space out well).